# How do I associate these models? Rails 3.2.13 Postgresql 9.1

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, postgresql-9.1

I have a basic task management application.  It has a class called Task which I used for tracking tasks.  It has another class called User which I used for authentication.

Task has a variable called 'user_email' and User has a variable called 'email'.  I would like to use these variables as foreign_keys.  Some Tasks 'user_email' may not actually belong to a user.  I do not want these associations to be dependent.

I would now like to associate users having many tasks. Then show the users tasks on the user show page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To associate a user having many tasks add the following line to your user model:

```
has_many :tasks
```

Now you also need to take care of the other side of the association. (ie. tasks to users) Presumably your tasks have just the one user? In this case, the task model will need the line:

```
belongs_to :user
```

To learn more about Associations in Rails I suggest you check out the Rails guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 0):

You **really** want to use IDs instead of emails to identify the owner of a task. Something like

```
class Task
  belongs_to :user
end

class User
  has_many :tasks
end
```

This requires you to add a integer field called `user_id` to the tasks table.

---

If you want to use the emails for identifying the users' tasks, you can still do it with

```
class User
  has_many :tasks, :conditions => ['user_email = #{self.email}']
end
```

Comment: You would still want to use the user id as the condition, but just query for the user first either using a authentication plugin, which provides a current_user helper or manually User.where(email: user_email)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way to handle this but this is what I am currently doing...

I basically wanted to display the tasks that the user_email is the same as the email of the current logged in user on their show page.

In users_controller.rb

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @tasks = Task.where(:user_email => @user.email)
end
```

In users/show.html.erb

```
<h1><%= @user.name %></h1>
<% @tasks.each do |task| %>
  <%= task.title %><br />
<% end %>
```

So I am accomplishing what I want to do without associating the models.  If anyone can suggest a better way to do this, please go ahead.